# Lord Kalki's wife

Tags: kalki, kalki-purana

Padma, the wife of lord kalki, prayed to Shiva as described in the Kalki purana. Shiva appeared before her and told her that every man who lustfully looks at her will be transformed in a woman. Padma was too shy to say something.

Why was she too shy to ask for a boon when Shiva appeared before her? And how did lord Shiva knew that this curse would be appropiate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How lord Shiva would know that this curse and/or boon is appropriate?**

If someone prays to God, then God knows what that person wants:

As per **chapter 4 of Kalki Purana**:

> Understanding that Kamala, whose face is exquisitely beautiful and who
>   is very dear to Lord Hari, had incarnated within this world, Sankara,
>   along with Parvarti, joyfully came to see her.

Lord Siva gives this boon:

> О fortunate one, you will receive Lord Narayana as your husband. He
>   will joyfully accept your hand in marriage. Rest assured that there is
>   no other prince on earth who is a suitable match for you.

Other than this boon, Lord Shiva gives below curse to others

> Anyone who lustily casts his glance upon you will immediately be
>   transformed into a woman, regardless of his age.
>
> Whether they be demigods, demons, Nagas, Gandharvas, Caranas,
>   or anyone else, if they simply desire to enjoy a conjugal relationship with
>   you, they will immediately transform in to women
>
> However, this curse is not applicable to Lord Hari, who is your only
>   husband. It is only applicable to others.

This must be an appropriate boon and/or curse as per Kalki Purana 4.45 (described in the later part of this answer).

---

Other incarnation of Goddess Lakshmi also worshiped Gauri and/or Shiva in order to get desired husband:

Rukmiṇī prayed:

> O mother Ambikā, wife of Lord Siva, I repeatedly offer my obeisances unto you, together with your children. May Lord Kṛṣṇa become my husband. Please grant this! - [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.53.46](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/53)

Sita also prayed:

> मज्जनु करि सर सखिन्ह समेता। गई मुदित मन गौरि निकेता।।
>
> पूजा कीन्हि अधिक अनुरागा। निज अनुरूप सुभग बरु मागा।।
>
> Having taken a dip into the lake with Her companions, Sita went with a glad heart to Girijå's temple. She offered worship with great devotion and begged of the Goddess a handsome match worthy of Her. - ***Ramcharitmanas 1.228***

---

**Why Padma stood too shy to ask for a boon when Shiva appears before her?**

As per **Kalki Purana 4.45**

> Having received her desired benediction from Lord Siva, Padmavati's
>   happiness knew no bound, so that her face blossomed brightly. She then
>   offered her obeisances to Uma and Mahadeva and returned home.

So it's clear that her prayers were to get desired husband. So a girl may feel shy in asking such boons. Also as God knows what a devotee is asking for so there is not need to ask explicitly.